# Can I search in different set of documents at every query, in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I wonder if I could enforce ES to perform search in a specific sublist of documents at every query, different for every query. (Imagine I have another agent that filters some of the documents based on external criteria).

Is this possible? Would it improve performance (especially if I narrow them down from thousands of documents to just a few)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) to every query, where filter is provided by agent. Thats one option . Filters wont affect relevancy .

Also if the filters are not much in numbers, but just updated - you can have an [alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) with filter which will be created/updated by agent as required.